# Compare elements of 2 maps - Am I doing this right?

Tags: concurrency, go

just started working with Go over the weekend and I'm unsure whether I used Go's peculiarities right, or whether I haven't done this "Go-like" at all.

The code is supposed to iterate over elements of a map called `non_placed_alleles` and compare each of these with all elements in `placed_alleles`, which are stored in a map as well. I'm trying to use one go-routine for each of the elements in `non_placed_alleles` as the comparison is quite costly and takes forever.

Here's a bit from the main-function:

```
runtime.GOMAXPROCS(8) // For 8 consecutive routines at once? got 10 CPUs
c := make(chan string)
for name, alleles := range non_placed_alleles {
    go get_best_places(name, alleles, &placed_alleles, c) 
    // pointer to placed_alleles as we only read, not write - should be safe?
}
for channel_item := range c {
    fmt.Println("This came back ", channel_item)
} 
// This also crashes with "all goroutines are sleeping", 
// but all results are printed
```

And here's the called function:

```
func get_best_places(name string, alleles []string, placed_alleles *map[string] []string, c chan string) {
    var best_partner string
    // Iterate over all elements of placed_alleles, find best "partner"
    for other_key, other_value := range *placed_alleles {
        best_partner := compare_magic() // omitted because boring
    }
    c <- best_partner
}
```

Is there any way to make this "better"? Faster? Have I used the pointer-magic and goroutines correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some observations:

- You probably want to use a bufered channel

  `c := make(chan string, someNumber) // someNumber >= goroutines cca`
- The deadlock stems from ranging a channel which no one closes (that's how the range statement terminates). Machinery to coordinate stuff in Go varies per task. Some would perhaps use in this case a [sync.WaitGroup](http://golang.org/pkg/sync/#WaitGroup). Please check thoroughly the example code located bellow the preceding link for hints about proper use of WaitGroup. An alternative is some/any other kind/way of counting the started vs finished workers (which WaitGroup encapsulates, but I tend to see it as an overkill).
- No need to pass pointers to map in this case. Maps in Go have full reference semantics (it's just a pointer under the hood anyway).

Comment: Thank you for that!

So the pointers to maps work like passing dictionaries in Python? Interesting.

Comment: You almost never need a pointer to a map, a map is a reference type. If you pass a map to a function that changes the contents of the map, the changes will be visible in the caller. That makes maps work exactly like dicts do in Python.

Comment: It's a good idea to get programs working & terminating with zero-sized channel buffers first (which should always be possible), then add buffering to improve performance later. This approach helps the learning process.

Comment: @Rick-777: I think one can write a program which deadlocks w/ non buffered channels and works correctly w/ buffered channels. At least for GOMAXPROCS=1 (the easy case).

Comment: Another quick question: When I run the above code with a buffered channel, I see the CPU-usage jump from 800% to 300, linger there a bit, and then go back. Is this because the buffer's full or are there any other reasons?

Comment: The "above" code is not a complete program so it's really hard to say anything about the run time behavior. I suggest to ask this at http://codereview.stackexchange.com/